# How to check the req.url path is existing in app?

Tags: node.js, url, routes, sequelize.js, middleware

I'm using sequelizejs, nodejs in my application. I know this will check inbuild, but I want to check manually like in if() condition.
Below is some url path

```
/user
/user/11d9b6130159 => user/:id
/user/11d9bdfg0159/sample => user/:id/sample
```

what I want is, there is Middleware, have to check current url these in app route like

```
if(url.parse(req.url).path === "/user"){
  //some action do
}
```

But I'm failing remaining urls. Please suggest the way to solve. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do the URL parsing manually then the aproach could be like this:

EDIT: Based on your comment, I modified the sample code (more than 3 levels). You can easily extend it based on your needs.

```
const url = require('url');

const path = ctx.request.href;
const pathName = url.parse(path).pathname;
const pathNameParts = pathName.split('/'');

if (pathNameParts && pathNameParts[1] && pathNameParts[1] === 'user') {
    if (pathNameParts[2]) {
        const id = pathNameParts[2];    // :id is now defined
        if (pathNameParts[3] && pathNameParts[3] === 'sample') {
            if (pathNameParts[4]) {
                const id2 = pathNameParts[4];   // :id2 is now defined
                if (pathNameParts[5] && pathNameParts[5] === 'disable') {
                    // do some action for /user/:id/sample/:id2/disable
                } else {
                    // do some action for /user/:id/sample/:id2
                }           
            } else {
                // do some action for /user/:id/sample
            }
        } else {
            // do some action for /user/:id
        }           
    } else {
        // do some action for /user
    }
}
```

So I would do this only, if you really want to do the parsing yourself. Otherwise use something like express router or koa router. Using express router it would be like:

```
app.use('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('ID:', req.params.id);
  next();
});
```

Comment: Suppose the url will be '/user/11d9bdfg0159/sample/df45g4435/disable'.. that is not only 3 level url.